# Django 4 with Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 initially loading but then stops working until Apache restart

Tags: django, apache, virtual-machine, ubuntu-22.04

I deployed my Django 4 project with a SQLITE3 DB using python 3.10 on an Ubuntu 22.04 Server instance on a virtual machine on my Synology NAS. I am using the WSGI module, which is to my knowledge the only way to do this, right?
My Synology NAS has an Intel Celeron processes and 10GB RAM (2 cores and 6 GB are available to the virtual machine, I also tried first with 4 GB)

Now after I managed that my website can be called and is displayed I am facing the issue that I can call any page initially I want and it displays as expected BUT then the browser tab indicates by a moving circle that still something is loading and I cannot navigate to any other URL within my application. even the language is displayed correctly depending on the browser language.
It also happens that after I restarted apache the next page loaded. Doing this I was even able to login to the admin UI in 2 steps, so the database is obviously accessible.

Meanwhile increased the log level to trace1 of the Apache server and now can see that after 5 minutes the process gets killed and restarted for any reason but at least my environment variables are correctly loaded: This I can see by using print statements to show them in the logs. I also granted explicit complete rights für :www-data to my data base as it seems to me like the application or Apache has an issue with maybe writuing to the database.
Below you find extracts of the erorr log and Myebsite.log Yes, I called it like that :-)

So I hope somebody here has the right clue for me, to get this running.
Thank you in advance!

#### EXTRACT from MyWebsite.log

Between 20:43 and 20:48 nothing happens until the process stops.

```
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.001088 2023] [deflate:trace1] [pid 834] mod_deflate.c(734): [client 192.168.175.42:51447] token: 'gzip' - q: ''
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.158541 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 832] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.175.42:51449] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://192.168.175.56/
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.158605 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 832] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.175.42:51449] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://192.168.175.56/
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.158822 2023] [deflate:trace1] [pid 832] mod_deflate.c(734): [client 192.168.175.42:51449] token: 'gzip' - q: '', referer: http://192.168.175.56/
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.167348 2023] [deflate:debug] [pid 832] mod_deflate.c(869): [client 192.168.175.42:51449] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 153402 to 22635 : URL /static/homepage/bootstrap.min.css, referer: http://192.168.175.56/
192.168.175.42 - - [26/Jan/2023:20:43:24 +0000] "GET /static/homepage/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 22993 "http://192.168.175.56/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.61"
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:23.835110 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Daemon process deadlock timer expired, stopping process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:23.835355 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Shutdown requested 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:24.023436 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 834] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.175.42:51447] mod_wsgi (pid=834): Failed to proxy response from daemon.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:24.023582 2023] [deflate:debug] [pid 834] mod_deflate.c(869): [client 192.168.175.42:51447] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 9409 to 3096 : URL /
192.168.175.42 - - [26/Jan/2023:20:43:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3562 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.61"
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:24.087213 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 834] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.175.42:51447] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://192.168.175.56/
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:24.087306 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 834] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.175.42:51447] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://192.168.175.56/
192.168.175.42 - - [26/Jan/2023:20:48:24 +0000] "GET /static/homepage/minion_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 249 "http://192.168.175.56/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.61"
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:28.836028 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Aborting process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:28.836241 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Exiting process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.768996 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1239] mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.791601 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1239] mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Adding '/var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite' to path.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.793603 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 0 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.794397 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 1 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.794441 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 4 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.794595 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 3 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.794677 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 2 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.794863 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 5 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.795137 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 6 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.795248 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 7 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.795994 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 14 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.796116 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 13 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.796215 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 12 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.796293 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 9 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.796373 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 11 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.796496 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 10 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.796591 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 1239] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9142): mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Started thread 8 in daemon process 'MyWebsite'.
```

#### EXTRACT error.log

```
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.685411 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 828] mod_watchdog.c(445): AH010033: Watchdog: Running with WatchdogInterval 1000ms
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.685641 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 828] mod_watchdog.c(454): AH02974: Watchdog: found parent providers.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.685661 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 828] mod_watchdog.c(500): AH02977: Watchdog: found child providers.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.685678 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 828] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_singleton_).
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.685694 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 828] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_default_).
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.686259 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 828] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(8512): mod_wsgi (pid=828): Socket for 'MyWebsite' is '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.828.0.1.sock'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.686405 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 828] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(8581): mod_wsgi (pid=828): Listen backlog for socket '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.828.0.1.sock' is '100'.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.690541 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Starting process 'MyWebsite' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.705603 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 828] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.705648 2023] [mpm_prefork:info] [pid 828] AH00164: Server built: 2022-09-30T04:09:50
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.705701 2023] [core:notice] [pid 828] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.705719 2023] [core:debug] [pid 828] log.c(1570): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.705736 2023] [mpm_prefork:debug] [pid 828] prefork.c(953): AH00165: Accept mutex: none (default: pthread)
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.706664 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 831] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.707440 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 832] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.712781 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 834] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.713025 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 833] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.718786 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 831] mod_wsgi (pid=831): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.719577 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Python home /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/venv.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.719790 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 832] mod_wsgi (pid=832): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.720365 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 834] mod_wsgi (pid=834): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.720460 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 833] mod_wsgi (pid=833): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.721846 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 830] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.722049 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 830] mod_wsgi (pid=830): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:52.796422 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 829] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:53.972677 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 834] mod_wsgi (pid=834): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:53.999176 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 832] mod_wsgi (pid=832): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:54.057680 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 833] mod_wsgi (pid=833): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:54.071090 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 831] mod_wsgi (pid=831): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:42:54.113752 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 830] mod_wsgi (pid=830): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:14.732936 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 1127] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:14.733171 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1127] mod_wsgi (pid=1127): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:14.792782 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1127] mod_wsgi (pid=1127): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.421107 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 1128] mod_watchdog.c(559): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.421327 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1128] mod_wsgi (pid=1128): Initializing Python.
[Thu Jan 26 20:43:24.485083 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1128] mod_wsgi (pid=1128): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.725192 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 828] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Process 'MyWebsite' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.725334 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 828] mod_wsgi (pid=829): Process 'MyWebsite' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.726543 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1239] mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Starting process 'MyWebsite' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.730090 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1239] mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Python home /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/venv.
[Thu Jan 26 20:48:29.730296 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 1239] mod_wsgi (pid=1239): Initializing Python.
```

#### Apache.conf seetings (i removed all commented lines)

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 1
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel trace1

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

#### MyWebsite.conf

```
VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@MyWebsite.com
        ServerName MyWebsite.com
        ServerAlias www.MyWebsite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/MyWebsite.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/MyWebsite.log combined

        Alias /static /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/static
        <Directory /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/media
        <Directory /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/media>
                Require all granted
         </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/MyWebsite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess MyWebsite python-path=/var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite python-home=/var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup MyWebsite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

#### WSGI.py

```
"""
WSGI config for MyWebsite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyWebsite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

from dotenv import load_dotenv
dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
```

#### List of Packages in VENV (python version: Python 3.10.6)

```
Package           Version
----------------- -------
asgiref           3.6.0
autopep8          2.0.1
Django            4.1.4
django-countries  7.5
pip               22.0.2
pycodestyle       2.10.0
python-dotenv     0.21.0
setuptools        59.6.0
sqlparse          0.4.3
tomli             2.0.1
typing_extensions 4.4.0
tzdata            2022.7
```

Comment: please post apache conf. Your virt env is python 3.10? which python packages are installed in virt. env?

Comment: I added my configurations above and also tried the following:
Running my site using the manage.py runserver command on the server and it worked well. 
I also copied a very simple website from a django only needing django installed and it worked well with manage.py runserver but had the same issues when using apache to deliver the website.
So I guess the root cause lies not within the actual code but probably somewhere in my (apache) configuration files.

Comment: I am also using the default sqlite3 database provided with the django package. Might this be an issue? I will also try this out in the next days.

Comment: this sounds like a wrong setup of apache/mod_wsgi How did you setup apache?  It is important that mod_wsgi is compiled for the python version you are using in the virt.env

Comment: I haven‘t compiled the mod_wsgi but just installed it using pip and apt Sounds like I also need to get familiar with compiling packages instead of just installing. Thank you for the hint hint I will try.

Comment: if you use pip you do not need to compile - see steps below in the answer

Comment: After trying a bit and checking the installed it worked after I ran the command 
mod_wsgi-express module-config 
and copied the LoadModule line to MyWebsite.conf but without the WSGSIPythonHome,. The last caused an apache failure, so I reoved it again and the nit worked

Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately for any reason it just seemed that the server was running ok for some clicks, but then after server restart the issue just occured as before without any further change of the configuration. I checked the memory and it is only 250MB used (4 GB are available). Any further ideas or what I could check?
This is getting very frustrating.

Comment: Additionally I detected that the behaviour is the same no matter of if the wsgi module is enabled  or disabled, so to me it seems like for any reason wsgi is not configured correctly, right?

Comment: I am still working on getting this up and running. At the moment it seems it could relate to the usage of the standard sqlite database instead of e.g. MySQL, so I am searching the Internet for any hint e.g. if I need a sqlite module for apache.

Answer (score 0):

its been a while but ... this is the steps I just took from a container based on Ubuntu Image:

```
> apt-get install apache2
> apt-get install apache2-dev
> ...env/bin/activate                   # activate virt env
> apt-get install mod_wsgi

> mod_wsgi-express module-config        # run the command and copy 2 output lines (see below example) from terminal to apache config file (not inside vhost/host)

something like:
LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/www/project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py310.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/var/www/project/env"

the rest seems ok in your vhost conf etc.
```

Comment: Finally I gave up on trying with Apache & wsgi und tried Gunicorn & Nginx which works now. Thank you!